# Laravel: Imagick and GD error at AWS Lambda with Bref

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, imagick

I set up an laravel application at AWS Lambda, using [Bref](https://github.com/brefphp/bref). Everything works fine, including filesystem and s3 filestorage. I use [spatie's medialibrary](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) to handle file upload and media conversions, and I can upload a file without any troubles.

The problem appear when I try to make image conversions, using either [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [Imagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

Whenever I try to make the conversions, I get the following errors:

When using Imagick:

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
Unable to read image from path (/tmp/Glide0PSwRU).
```

When using GD:

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
Unsupported image type. GD driver is only able to decode JPG, PNG, GIF or WebP files.
```

This only happens when running the application at AWS Lambda. If I run at my local environment or at another service like Google App Engine, with the "same" code configs (related to the upload/media conversion).

Answer (score 2):

Create a `php/conf.d/php.ini` in your project
then add `extension=imagick` or `extension=gd` to enable these extensions

You can read the docs [here](https://bref.sh/docs/environment/php.html#extensions)